# Text attributes not showing up in rich UITextView (iOS 6)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm trying the set the font color for some initial text in a iOS 6 UITextView.  When running in the UI 6 simulator, the view comes up, but the attributes aren't rendered.  Am I missing something?

```
NSAttributedString *as = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:boilerText
    attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      NSForegroundColorAttributeName, [UIColor redColor] ,
      NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName,
          [NSNumber numberWithInt:  NSUnderlineStyleSingle],nil]
      ];

_descriptionView.attributedText = as;
```

Answer (score 8):

The method says dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys. You've gotten your objects and keys reversed. Try this:

```
NSAttributedString *as = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:boilerText
     attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
     [UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, 
     [NSNumber numberWithInt: NSUnderlineStyleSingle], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName,
     nil]];
```